# Universal way to scale image to given specific range

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning

As if we want to scale an image to (0 , 1) , 
we had alot of formula like

```
scaled_img = img / 250.0
```

Also there are alot other scaling like (-1, 1), ( 1, 0) ....

Is there any universal way to make function find scaled number given two or more range as arguments ,

```
def scale_option(start, end):
    pass
```

Comment: That would be too complex to do I guess.

Comment: it's just scale and shifts... the scale is given by the ratio of the input range and the output range, the shifts by the the input min and output min